# Build Error C00CE014 due to 200+ resources in AppxManifest.xml

Tags: c#, uwp, localization, visual-studio-2017

I'm building a UWP application and I'm getting a build error when the number of resources is 200+ with Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.4.  If I reduce the number of resources below 200 then it builds just fine.  Is this a limitation for the Community version?  I intend to submit the app to the Microsoft Store and unless I limit the markets the app will fail because it doesn't support all of the required language codes which are included as resource files.

I've tried building a project from scratch...steps to reproduce detailed below.  I've reduced the resource list but now I'm faced with denying my app to some markets because I believe the Microsoft Store won't accept my app for that market unless it supports the language for that market.

1. Start Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.4 with Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.3 NuGet package (and no other NuGet packages) if that makes any difference.
2. Click and Select `File=>New=>Project` from main menu.
3. Select `Windows Universal=>Blank App` (Universal Windows) then click OK.
4. Select Target version 17763 and Min version 16299 then Click OK (but the same error occurs with other version settings).
5. Select `Project=>Store=>Create App Packages`.
6. Select "I want to create packages for sideloading" (but the same error occurs with a Store App) then click Next.
7. Click Create to accept the defaults.
8. Click OK to close the popup indicating that the package was created.
9. Click Build Solution or press F6.
10. Right click on the app project and select New Folder then rename it Localization.
11. Right-click on the Localization folder and select New Folder.
12. Name the folder using one of the Supported Language Codes listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/supported-languages.
13. Right click on the new folder and select Add=>New Item.
14. Select XAML=>Resources File (.resw) then click Add.
15. Enter any value, for example String1, for the String1 Name and save it.
16. Create additional sub folders for all supported language codes and copy the same resource file into those folders.
17. Add those resource files to the project.
18. Try to build the project.

**Result:**

```
Error       Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 223, Column 6, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Resource' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Resources'. App1    C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\UWP\App1\App1\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

**Note:** Line 223 is the line where the 200th resource line: `<Resource Language="LT" />` is located.  However, the error goes away if Resources.resw files are removed from the project until there are 202 or less localization resources in the project.  This error is preventing my UWP applications from being available to all supported markets.

Comment: [submit it as error to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Look that, in order to submit your app to all markets, you don’t necessarily need to create all those .resw files... where a certain national language isn’t found, it will peek up the standard one specified in the AppManifest.